# Importing custom icons into React Native 0.62

Tags: react-native, fonts, react-native-vector-icons, icomoon

I'm trying to import and use my own custom icons in my `React Native 0.62.2` app.

I followed the steps outlined here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#custom-fonts but so far the icons are not showing up.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Created my icon set and converted it to fonts on https://icomoon.io
2. Downloaded the zip file from `IcoMoon` and placed the `ttf` file into `./src/assets/fonts` folder
3. I then created `react-native-config.js` file and placed in the root. The code in this file is down below
4. Under my components folder, I created `CustomIcon.js` -- see code below
5. I also placed the `selection.json` file that was included in the `zip` file I downloaded from `IcoMoon` in the same folder as `CustomIcon.js`
6. I then used the `CustomIcon` as shown below

So here what the codes look like:

The `react-native-config.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/']
  };
```

The `CustomIcon.js` file looks like this:

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

import icoMoonConfig from './selection.json';
export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig, 'StreamLine', '../../../assets/fonts/streamline-icon-set-1.ttf');
```

And here's how I use the icon:

```
import CustomIcon from '../common_components/fonts/CustomIcon';

<CustomIcon name="home-outline" />
```

When I run the app in `Android Emulator`, I see the missing icon symbol i.e. a box with an X in it.

Any idea what the issue is here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good article which helped me with this problem.

[Custom icon fonts with React Native](https://www.orangejellyfish.com/blog/custom-icon-fonts-with-react-native/)

Comment: thanks, forgot the obvious step of loading the fonts after

Answer (score 1):

There is always issue with custom icons. When I personally bump into such condition I do these:

> Rename the `react-native-config.js` to `react-native.config.js`
>
> Re-run the app by restarting metro
>
> Make sure I have correct path to my assets in `react-native.config.js`
>
> `react-native link` and restart. It copies your assets to corresponding ios and android folders

If neither do not help I copy the assets manually to folder: `Project/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`

Comment: Done all of these and still the icons won't show. This does seem like a common problem! I'd appreciate any other suggestions you may have.

Comment: Do you see your fonts in this folder? `Project/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`

Comment: Yes, they’re there

Comment: Then watch your `config.js` there might be incorrect imports or the icon might be defined twice.

Comment: Which `config.js`? The `react-native.config.js`?

Comment: Do I need to install the `react-native-config` `npm` package? In the instructions, it said create a `react-native-config.js` file and I did. Do I need to configure anything in the app for this file to be read?

Comment: Sorry I mean selection.json file. Observe that file there might me incorrect configs or duplicate imports!

Comment: I have created a new app to reproduce the bug. The bug here is you have named `react-native-config.js` but it should be `react-native.config.js`. Rename it and repeat above steps!